# Strange return with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this :

```
$somestring= "10, Albalala STREET 11 (768454)";
```

the for mat could change a little bit like :

```
$somestring= "10, Albalala STREET 11 (S) 768454 ";
```

or

```
$somestring= "10, Albalala STREET 11 (S) ( 768454 )";
```

I want to use regex in php to get that 6 digits number (which is the postal code).

```
$regex_pattern = "/^\d{6}$/";
preg_match_all($regex_pattern,$somestring,$matches);
print_r("postalcode: " . $matches);//
```

The result I got is :

```
postalcode: Array
```

not a number 768454
Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Don't use the start and end anchors, you're looking for a string that has only 6 numbers.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because probably it would not be useful. Anyway, if you are still curious why `Array` is printed, here's the reason. `preg_match_all` assigns array with matched values to the third parameter. And later, when you concatenate this array with string array is represented with string `Array`.

Comment: Thanks but who minus my question, I do researched and tested before asking this question. Its not fair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression does not match because of `^` and `$`. Instead use `\b` (word boundary).

To get only the digits, access it by `$matches[0][0]`:

```
$somestring= "10, Albalala STREET 11 (768454)";
$regex_pattern = "/\b\d{6}\b/";
preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $somestring, $matches);
print_r($matches[0][0]); # => 768454
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$a = '10, Albalala STREET 11 (S) ( 768454 )';
$a = preg_replace('/\D{1,}$/', '', $a); // remove non digit chars at the end
preg_match_all('/\d{6}$/',$a,$matches);
$val = $matches[0];
print_r("postalcode: " . $val[0]);//
```